# Unable to post array in JSON to WebAPI method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

This is my method:

```
[HttpPut("*myUri}")]
    public Task<IActionResult> DoSomething(string myString, [FromBody]string[] myIDs)
{
// DO stuff
}
```

I am sending the following JSON in the body of my request:

```
{
   "myIDs": ["1","2","3"]
}
```

Why is myIDs null when the API gets called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller is expecting a string array, but you're sending an object that looks like

```
{
    myIDs: ["1", "2", "3"]
}
```

Try posting *just* `JSON.stringify(["1", "2", "3"])`, and sure you're sending the Content-Type as *application/json*

Comment: Comment is application/json and I'm using SoapUI to send the request.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one `[FromBody] IEnumerable<string> myIDs` Instead of `[FromBody]string[] myIDs` and use the JSON as `["1","2","3"]`

Answer (score 0):

Please start reading something about Json. Maybe [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp)?

Given the parameter `[FromBody]string[] myIDs`, it expects a Json like this:

```
[
    "This is", 
    "your",
    "array of strings."
]
```

`[` and `]` defines an array of objects.

With your given Json:

```
{
   "myIDs": ["1","2","3"]
}
```

If you want to get this type of Json, change your parameter into something like this:

```
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]myClass this_Is_Just_A_Name)
    {
        return Ok(this_Is_Just_A_Name);
    }

public class myClass
{
    public string[] myIDs { get; set; }
}
```